# Ember.js, set(), and computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-properties

I'm reading through the [Ember.js API reference](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Observable/methods/set?anchor=set) of the `set()` method and I'm not understanding one particular paragraph.

> Computed Properties
>
> If you try to set a value on a key that has a computed property
>   handler defined (see the get() method for an example), then set() will
>   call that method, passing both the value and key instead of simply
>   changing the value itself. This is useful for those times when you
>   need to implement a property that is composed of one or more member
>   properties.

I understand how `set()` works independently, but setting computed properties (the function) is still not clicking, even after reading this paragraph.

Could anyone please give additional explanation or an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties for better understanding.

Here I am just trying to explain the same thing.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    fullNameCP: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
        return `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`
    }),
    fullNameCPwithGetSet: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', {
        get(key) {
            return `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`;
        },
        set(key, value) {
            let [firstName, lastName] = value.split(/\s+/);
            this.set('firstName', firstName);
            this.set('lastName', lastName);
            return value;
        }
    })
});
```

In the above,
if we say, `this.set('fullNameCP','Yehuda Katz')` after that it will be treated as normal property it will not be treated as computed property. You should not set `fullNameCP` to new value manually. if you want to do that then you need to define Computed property with Getter and Setter like  `fullNameCPwithGetSet`.

if we say, `this.set('fullNameCPwithGetSet','Yehuda Katz')`, then it will call `set` method of computed property `fullNameCPwithGetSet` by passing value too ie., `Yehuda Katz` so that we can set the exact value for the dependent key.

Comment: When you say, "after that it will be treated as normal property", what exactly do you mean ? Any example to check the behavior ? At what point does that happen ?

Comment: Also, does using Ember.set(a, b,c) have the same effect ?

Comment: It means, when you set value for computed property which has no getters, that means it will not be recalculated if there is any depentant property change.

Comment: `Also, does using Ember.set(a, b,c) have the same effect` - Yes `Ember.set`  and `this.set` is same.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases `a.set(b, c)` won't trigger computed values. So we can use `set(a, b, c)`
where

a = yourObject, b = the Property Which You Have To Modify, c = the value